# Must a beit din be exactly 3 people?

Tags: halacha, number, beit-din-court

Must a small court be exactly 3 people, or could it be larger, like 4 or 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> אף על פי שבית דין של שלושה, בית דין שלם הוא, כל זמן שהן רבים, הרי זה משובח
>   Although a court of three is considered as a complete entity, whenever there are more judges, it is praiseworthy.

[Rambam Sanhedrin 2:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e102.htm#13) ([English](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1172725))

Comment: What about בית דין שקול? (Gemara in a few [places](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=101&format=pdf) and [Rambam](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=79&perek=5&halocha=3&hilite=))

Comment: Presumably it refers to any odd number.